# Error: cannot import name Lookup

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I cannot find any similar questions.

Why

```
"Error: cannot import name Lookup" when I run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000?
```

Searching Lookup, I found:

```
from django.db.models import Lookup
import ast

class CIDRLookup( Lookup ):
```

On the doc, it said Lookup is builtin.  My Django is 1.3.1. Is is the issue of Django version? How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Django 1.3.1. Lookups [were introduced in 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-lookups/). You need to upgrade.

Well, wait, *Django 1.3.1 is 5 years old*, now you seriously need to upgrade.

Comment: The ubuntu we are using is 12.04. I have no idea why we started to use higher version of packages before upgrading ubuntu.

Comment: There's no reason to use the Ubuntu package. Install Django directly via pip.

Comment: Now, I will use Django by pip. Thanks all of you